# Search Filter is not working after upgraded Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla1.5

I have upgraded Joomla from 1.5 to 3.4. I have upgraded Vodes payement component also. After Upgradation Search Filter option is not working on administrator. This is the code I am using:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align="right" width="100%">
        <?php echo JText::_( 'Filter' ); ?>:
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="<?php echo $this->lists['search'];?>" class="text_area" onChange="document.adminForm.submit();" />
        <button onclick="this.form.submit();"><?php echo JText::_( 'Go' ); ?></button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('search').value='';
this.form.getElementById('filter_catid').value='0';
this.form.getElementById('filter_state').value='';
this.form.submit();">
<?php echo JText::_( 'Reset' ); ?></button>
    </td>
```

Please help me to sought it out.

Answer (score 0):

That might be due to the way you upgraded from 1.5 to 3.4. It's a gigantic leap, so it wouldn't be no wonder if something went wrong in the process.